# How to restore a jailbroken iphone 5s?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, restore, iphone

I have a jailbroken iPhone 5s 32gb. After the jailbreak my iPhone is detecting by iTunes, but It would not back up, restore, or sync. It is just stuck on iTunes. What is the procedure to restore the original iOS software? I can connect to my PC only itunes. "not detecting on other PC itunes"

Comment: What does " I can connect to my PC only itunes. "not detecting on other PC iTunes"" mean

Comment: Are you OK with the edit implying that you will lose your jailbreak and just drop a factory clean / latest OS on the phone?

Comment: how about my data? I can connect to my PC itunes only. Cannot connect to any other PC itunes. and when I try to do a backup it's not backing up. just freezing.

Comment: I don't need my jailbreak. I'm done with it. it's not worth for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot the phone into DFU mode.

1. Plug the iPhone cable into the phone and the computer, with iTunes open.
2. Turn off the device.
3. Hold the Power button for 3 seconds.
4. Hold the Home and Power buttons for 10 seconds.
5. Release the Power button but keep holding the Home button until iTunes recognises the phone.

The screen will turn on, but it will be black. iTunes will recognise the phone in DFU mode and give you the option to restore.